# Bake Animation didn't work

Tags: animation, rigify

I was following tutorial from CGDive on Youtube and i encountered problem after i bake the animation from Rig to Metarig.

In the video CGDive told after succeeded baking the animation,hide bones' constraints and the animation should work.but my bones' didn't have any constraints at all and my animation still didn't work.if anyone have solutions please help.

[here's my blend file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PblmVkVvuaSv8FkGx4L337bYwqxReJLd/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Hi, this is Todor from CGDive. I understand you were watching one of my videos but I don't think you were following the content of the video. I would *never* suggest baking an animation to the Metarig. Can you share a link to the video you are following?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sJzMurUbQp0&t=199s

if you are so kindly and have time could you check my blend file?I'm stuck and didn't know what to do.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Are you following the full series? If you don't have constraints it could be because you never added them? Or maybe you checked "Clear constraints" and that deleted them. I checked your file and you don't have a game rig there so I assume you didn't really follow the series.

Comment: thanks for the reply todor!and yeah you're right apparently there's a section i skipped (don't know how and when)and now it works perfectly,especially after i discovered your game rig ready add-on.truly saves so much time.sorry for the trouble

Comment: Nice and I am glad you found GRT useful!